# Convertir un tipo string o int a un tipo entidad o model en c#

Tags: c#, .net, vue.js, relaciones, guardar

Estoy haciendo un POST mediante vue.js, y al momento que mi JSON llega al Backend me arroja el siguiente error.

Anexo JSON:

```
{
agencia: "Agencia N"
apellidoMaterno: "Lopez"
apellidoPaterno: "Lopez"
area: 13
fechaIngreso: "10/01/1989"
grupo_cc: "Vikingos"
jefeDirecto: "Yo"
nombre: "Alonso"
numeroEmpleado: "893489"
puesto: 8
turno: "1"
}
```

[image: Error que arroja el navegador en consola]

Mi función que realiza el guardar es el siguiente:

```
// POST: api/Empleado
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Crear([FromBody] Empleado empleado)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }


            Empleado e = new Empleado
            {

                Agencia = empleado.Agencia,                
                NumeroEmpleado = empleado.NumeroEmpleado,
                Nombre = empleado.Nombre,
                ApellidoMaterno = empleado.ApellidoMaterno,
                ApellidoPaterno = empleado.ApellidoPaterno,
                FechaIngreso = empleado.FechaIngreso,
                FechaCreacion=DateTime.Today,
                JefeDirecto = empleado.JefeDirecto,
                Turno = empleado.Turno,
                puesto = empleado.puesto,
                area=empleado.area,
            };

            _context.Empleados.Add(empleado);
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

Anexo el codigo de mi modelo Empleado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo claro que no puedo guardar un string o int en public Puesto puesto {get;set;} ya que puesto es un tipo Puesto.

Estoy iniciando con c#, les agradecería me dieran una pista de como puedo hacer esa conversion.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El json debes respectar la estrutuca de la clase con la cual debe realizar el `model binding`, si la propiedad `puesto` y `area` son clases debes enviar de esa forma el json

```
{
    agencia: "Agencia N",
    apellidoMaterno: "Lopez",
    apellidoPaterno: "Lopez",
    area: { 
        AreaId: 13
    },
    fechaIngreso: "10/01/1989",
    grupo_cc: "Vikingos",
    jefeDirecto: "Yo",
    nombre: "Alonso",
    numeroEmpleado: "893489",
    puesto: { 
        PuestoId: 8 
    },
    turno: "1" 
}
```

Como observas estas propiedades se definen ente `{}` llaves para indicar que es un objeto, puse las propiedades a modo de ejemplo, por supuesto deberias adaptarlas a las que tienes en las clases `Puesto` y `Area` que defines en codigo c#

Nota: ojo que en el json que muestras de ejemplo le esta faltando las `comas` al final de cada propiedad